# Why there is no tree tag in html?

Tags: html, tree, tags

I wonder why there is no tree tag in html? Something like table tag.

For example:

```
<tree>
  <treenode id=root>
    <treenode id=child1 />
    <treenode id=child2>
       <treenode id=child2-1>
       ......
       </treenode>
    </treenode>
  </treenode>
</tree>
```

**Edit**: well actually I did not get a clear answer to this question. I think this was not a valid question. But putting the answer from cherouvim beside comment from Anwar Chandra together, I think I've got the answer to my question.

Comment: You're going to have to explain a *lot* more before you'll get reasonable answers. What do you mean by "tree"? Binary tree? Tree of bulleted lists (nested <ul>s)? Christmas tree?

Comment: +1 for the Christmas tree, Tim :-). aforloney: That was simply the lack of formatting in the source.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that once the edit came around :x

Comment: because there's DOM trees, other tree will make us confusing.

Comment: "...Yeah, just noticed that once the edit came around :x ..."
Sorry, actually it was my first post here and did'nt notice code formating. 
"... You're going to have to explain a lot more before you'll get..."
Well I thought when I say "like table tag" it is clear what I mean. I encountered the question as I was working with RichFaces and wanted to write a javascript to do something with their tree. But the tree is on the client side implemented as combination of table and divs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is. Nested lists (ul, or ol).

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>test
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>example</li>
</ul>
```

And with the help of CSS and JS you can make the tree look and interact like, for example, the windows explorer.

Comment: Uh, no, there isn't. Still +1.

Comment: Well, yes. Technically there isn't :)

Answer (score 0):

If you say: ok a directory structure is some kind of technical glossary, the DL/DD/DT construction might be a good solution.

The difference to the usage of `<ul>` is that you can seperate the foldername and the childrens.

```
<dl>
  <dt>C:</dt>
  <dd>
     <dl>
       <dt>WINDOWS</dt>
       <dt>USERS</dt>
       <dt>ProgramData</dt>
     </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

C:

WINDOWS

USERS

ProgramData

---

**Beware**: Neither DL nor UL/OL is a perfect match for directory-structures. You could add your very own, custom tags to have a better match like `<folder>`.